# invalid matchers when mocking

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito

I want to test this method :

```
public void some_method(SomeFactory someFactory) {
        A a = someFactory.populateWithParameter(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4); 
        a.method_call();
        ....   
    }
```

the factory goes this way

```
public class SomeFactory(){

 // some constructor
public A populateWithParameter(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2, String string, int parameter){
 return new A(someClass1, someClass2, string, parameter)
} 
}
```

and the test is

```
public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        SomeFactory someFactory = mock(SomeFactory.class);
        when(someFactory.populateWithParameter(
                any(SomeClass1.class), any(SomeClass2.class),
             anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(notNull());

        mainActivity.some_method(someFactory);
...
    }
```

I get this message

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is because you are trying to return a matcher in your thenReturn(notNull()). Could you try returning an instance of A (or a mocked version)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26418391/6526330

Comment: @Dr.Nitpick I already tried to return an instance, but it does not work !

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what actually happens?

Comment: If the rest of your test doesn't actually throw an exception try removing `throws Exception`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to use `notNull()` as a return value. Mockito matchers only stand in for arguments in calls to `when` and `verify`, and cannot work as return values. In particular, `notNull()` will actually *return null* and mark the "not null" match as a side-effect on a hidden stack, where it lingers until you interact with the mock next (when you actually invoke `some_method`).

Though you didn't list your stack trace for your `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`, I'll bet that the error actually happens when you *invoke* `populateWithParameter` via `some_method`, not when you stub `populateWithParameter`. The "1 recorded" matcher is `notNull()`, where "4 matchers expected" refer to the number of arguments in the method call. The error message is really tailored for a case where you forget to use a matcher for some argument, like `populateWithParameter(any(), any(), anyString(), 42)`, which is a very common mistake.

Though I see in the comments that "it does not work!" when you try to return an instance, I can guarantee that returning `notNull()` absolutely will cause a problem, whereas returning an instance may simply reveal a *different* problem. You may want to update your question with the full stack trace after switching to returning an instance, or ask a new question.

For more information about Mockito matchers behind the scenes, see [my question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).